# Application running in a particular directory after installation

Tags: installation, discord, fedora

I am running Fedora 36. On my way to install Discord, I came through a process, here it is:

1. Downloaded discord.rar.gz
2. Unpack the file
3. Open the extracted directory
4. Found the file Discord with no extension: [image: See the image when I run]
5. I just double-clicked the file, it started installing (in GUI).

After it was installed, I still could not find it in App Drawer and when I run the same Discord file with no extension, it just opens the Discord app. [image: Here's a screenshot of the Properties of the file.]
I am curious to know what's happening here. How can I get the app in the app drawer? Note that I tried copying the file to another location and then double-clicking it. It did nothing.

I clicked the file Discord in the directory. I was expecting that it was an installer and it would install the application, and it would be available in the app drawer. But, after it was installed, it didn't appear in the app drawer. Also double-clicking the same file again, opens the Discord app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the steps to take if you want to keep changes to a minimum:

[Download Discord for Linux tar.gz](https://discordapp.com/api/download?platform=linux&format=tar.gz)

Create the directory where you will install Discord

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/discord
```

Extract and store in the directory created in the previous step

```
sudo tar xvzf discord-0.0.17.tar.gz -C /usr/share/discord
```

Copy the application launcher to the right place

```
sudo cp /usr/share/discord/Discord/discord.desktop /usr/share/applications
```

Point the icon to the right location

```
sudo sed -i 's|Icon=discord|Icon=/usr/share/discord/Discord/discord.png|g' /usr/share/applications/discord.desktop
```

Now if you go to **Applications > Internet** should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the app, or delete everything associated with it. Redownload, move to applications, and there open it for the first time (install it), that should do the work

Comment: By `applications`, did you mean to say the applications directory in `usr`?

Comment: yes, or usr/share/applications the other option I was going to give you was to create a link, Dan M gave the process, if you do not want to uninstall and redownload, just do the steps from Copy the application launcher. In that case, I think your OG path would be Home/satyam/downloads/discord/Discord/discord.desktop